# What do letters enclosed by two single quotes next to a function argument mean?

Tags: rust, lapack

I tried using LAPACK bindings for Rust when I came over some syntax that I could not find anything about.

The example code from https://github.com/stainless-steel/lapack:

```
let n = 3;

let mut a = vec![3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0];
let mut w = vec![0.0; n];
let mut work = vec![0.0; 4 * n];
let lwork = 4 * n as isize;
let mut info = 0;

lapack::dsyev(b'V', b'U', n, &mut a, n, &mut w, &mut work, lwork, &mut info);

for (one, another) in w.iter().zip(&[2.0, 2.0, 5.0]) {
    assert!((one - another).abs() < 1e-14);
}
```

What does *b'V'* and *b'U'* mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b'A'` means to create a *byte literal*. Specifically, it will be a `u8` containing the ASCII value of the character:

```
fn main() {
    let what = b'a';
    println!("{}", what);
    // let () = what;
}
```

The commented line shows you how to find the type.

`b"hello"` is similar, but produces a reference to an array of `u8`, a *byte string*:

```
fn main() {
    let what = b"hello";
    println!("{:?}", what);
    // let () = what;
}
```

Things like this are documented in the [*Syntax Index*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/syntax-index.html) which is currently only available in the nightly version of the docs.

Answer (score 4):

It creates a `u8` value with the ASCII value of the char between quote.

For ASCII literals, it's the same as writing `'V' as u8`.

Also, the `b` prefix on a double quoted string will create a byte array containing the UTF8 content of the string.

```
let s: &[u8; 11] = b"Hello world";
```